# Run an exe in client machine from a website

Tags: c#, asp.net, exe

We have developed an exe and we have created a website to download that exe.

Now is there any possibility to run that exe on a single button click in the client machine. ie if user clicks on a button in the website it has to download and run that exe.

So while clicking the link button, it have to show a "Run" dialogue box instead of the "save" dialogue box.

And upon clicking the "Run" it have to save and run the exe in the client machine.

Can anyone give suggestions for this.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is not possible to automate that process due to security concerns. The only thing that comes to mind is to write something like:

```
    <a href="myfile.exe" type="application/octet-stream">Download</a>
```

But that will only prompt the user to either run it or save it. To be honest, you are better off just documenting the procedure for your users/visitors to follow.

Hope it helps!

Answer (score 1):

This is not possible to the best of my knowledge.

However, you can get close with a trusted Silverlight 5 app. If all your users are on the intranet and within a domain, you can push your certificate and register it through group policy.

Comment: can you please elaborate, since i am not familiar with silverlight.

Answer (score 1):

Sounds like [ClickOnce](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ClickOnce) is what you're after?

Comment: but by using ClickOnce also, it will prompt a save dialogue box and have to save it first and then have to manually run it. But i need something like it have to execute automatically after saving it.

Answer (score 0):

What you are describing is a function of your browser.  The downloading and running of the exe is dependent upon the users browser.  More importantly there is a major security problem where the OS may throw prompts about trusting and running an unknown executable.