# How can I execute an EXE file in asp.net website?

Tags: asp.net, vb.net, exe

I have a website in asp.net with VB, and I have a link to a medical program that is installed in PC, when I click the link I want to execute the .exe for this program. I found this code but it´s works only when my project is locally:

```
 System.Diagnostics.Process.Start("C:\Windows\System32\MiProgram.exe")
```

I also tried with this code:

```
 Dim OpenDoc As ProcessStartInfo = New ProcessStartInfo
 Dim stPath As String = "C:\Windows\System32\MiProgram.exe"
 OpenDoc.FileName = stPath
 OpenDoc.Verb = "open"
 OpenDoc.WindowStyle = ProcessWindowStyle.Normal
 Process.Start(OpenDoc)
```

Both codes works locally, but when I get my project to the web, does nothing

I also read that I can enable de IIS Service, I follow the steps of [this page](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/kb/555134), but is not use to me.
Is there any solution to this problem?

I accept suggestions. 
Thanks.

Comment: Seems rights issue, this post may help you.

Comment: You cannot start an EXE file if user click it on the browser. It is a security measure. All browser will block it, even to download is today not always possible without tons of warnings.

Comment: Apologies for not adding the link to post, here it is, http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13658555/need-to-execute-exe-in-server-from-asp-net

Comment: Your code will run the program on the server, not on the client. This is why it "works" locally.

Comment: @Stanley , I know that is a security measure, but I thought that is there any way in the client pc to enable to open links, this pc is only to execute this program, it will not be a computer to surf the Internet or use other tools

Comment: @KevinM , yes your right but I want to know is there any posibility to connect the client pc?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to execute an application on the client from a website?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7814339/how-to-execute-an-application-on-the-client-from-a-website)

Comment: @Esraa_92 in order to run an exe on a machine, last web browser supports this is IE8, and this can be done using ActiveX controls, if you can ask who ever using this web site to use IE8 its doable :)

Answer (score 1):

Unfortunately, it is not possible to run a program on the client from server-side.
There is already some discussions about that, here is some links :

[How to execute an application on the client from a website?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7814339/how-to-execute-an-application-on-the-client-from-a-website)

[Run an exe in client machine from a website](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9731475/run-an-exe-in-client-machine-from-a-website)

[Executing exe on client side using C#](https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/6ccfe4cf-e390-4f28-8583-971cbd0228fc/executing-exe-on-client-side-using-c?forum=Vsexpressvcs)

Answer (score 1):

You can do this with a work around..

You create a running Windows Forms application, on that application you host a wcf services, check this [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5231867/hosting-wcf-service-inside-a-windows-forms-application) as sample.

Expose a method like `RunApplication' put the same code their, where you can call it from your website, this will 100% work.

Comment: Thank you for your answer, do you have another examples to show that? thanks

Comment: @Esraa_92 is already included a sample code, for your page ( according to this sample) you will be calling using ajax http://localhost:8080/MyWcfService/

Answer (score 0):

You can try by implementing this settings:

> In IIS 7/8 go Control Panel / Program And Features / Turn Windows
>   features on or off, and check all items from: Web Managment Tools,
>   (it's include: IIS Managment Service, II 6 Managment Compatibility)

Comment: Thanks for your contribution I do this before, but doesn´t work.